# Why google-iosched can save fragment state while navigating with navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller

Overall look at the code, I don't understand why it can be done.
https://github.com/google/iosched
[image]

from apps/iosched/ui/MainActivity.kt, It initialized NavController and NavHostFragment, but seems that there is no special treatment.
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/main/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/MainActivity.kt

```
    val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(TOP_LEVEL_DESTINATIONS)
private val TOP_LEVEL_DESTINATIONS = setOf(
            R.id.navigation_feed,
            R.id.navigation_schedule,
            R.id.navigation_map,
            R.id.navigation_info,
            // R.id.navigation_agenda, comment will not stop saving the statement.
            R.id.navigation_codelabs,
            R.id.navigation_settings
        )
```

from apps/iosched/ui/AgendaFragment.kt: the most simplest fragment, BindingAdapter method will always init AgendaAdapter(), but It can save the position of RecyclerView after init.
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/main/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/agenda/AgendaFragment.kt

Why can it save the State of each fragment?

Answer (score 0):

IOSched [depends on Navigation 2.4.1](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/039fdd715259dc3b7dc2f4ca87346a90e88b4eab/buildSrc/src/main/java/Versions.kt#L32). As per the [release notes of Navigation 2.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0):

> The NavController ... has been expanded to support saving and restoring the back stack.
>
> As part of this change, the `NavigationUI` methods of `onNavDestinationSelected()`, `BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController()` and `NavigationView.setupWithNavController()` now automatically save and restore the state of popped destinations, enabling support for [multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134) without any code changes. When using Navigation with Fragments, this is the recommended way to integrate with multiple back stacks.

And IOSched [uses `setupWithNavController`](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/039fdd715259dc3b7dc2f4ca87346a90e88b4eab/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/MainActivity.kt#L143), which means each tab is automatically going to save and restore its state correctly.

That includes the state of a `RecyclerView`, which has always supported saving and restoring its position automatically.

Comment: I have a fragment containing ViewPager2 with child-fragment tabs, how can I save the state?

Comment: That seems like a totally separate question that would require your actual code. If you're following the [ViewPager2 guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2) and [saving your fragment's state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state), then that already just works. I'd suggest opening another question with your actual code, what you expect, and what you are seeing so that we can help debug it. You could even link that other question here :)